# desktop responsive chat board using css

Tags: html, css

Am trying to build a responsive chat templates using Css.
Below is what am trying to achieve
1.) I want the chat templates to be responsive so that it will automatically fits into the screen of any desktop devices

2.)The scrolling Bar for **both Left Messages,right messages and center messages** is not working.

3.) I want to give chat header/Chatboard height of 10%, footer 10%,left message div 20% width, right messages 20% width, center message will take the remaining 60% width.

The code below shows my effort so far. Can someone help me fix that.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #009DA5;
}

.container {
  /*background:black;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 450px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*top:0px;*/
}

.chat-header {
  width: 98%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #273c57;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  /*top:0px;*/
}

#chat-body {
  /*display: none;*/
}

.message-left {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #F94D4D;
  /*position:fixed;*/
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.message-right {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  /*position:fixed;*/
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.message-center {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  font: normal 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 6px 18px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  color: purple;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

footer a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div id="chat-body">
      <div class="chat-header">
         <span>chat Board</span>
      </div>
      <div class="message-left">
         <ul>
            left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>v left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>left
            message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="message-right">
         <ul>
            right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br> right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>
            <br><br>right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="message-center">
         <div style="background:black;color:white;height:50px;postion:fixed">Rooms Names</div>
         <ul>
            main message<br><br><br>main message<br><br><br>main message<br><br><br>main message<br><br><br>main message
            <br><br><br>main message
            <br><br><br>main message<br><br><br>main message
            <br><br><br>main message
            <br><br><br>main message
            <br><br><br>main message
            <br><br><br>main message
            <br><br><br>main message
            <br><br><br>main message
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<footer>
   My footer is here
</footer>
</div>
```

[image: chat box]

Comment: is this what you're going for? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/XgVqow?editors=1100

Comment: @Michael Coker. You are too good. Just one thing left. how do I make the Room Name inside the center message to be fix so that it does not scroll up and down along with the center message. The room name div can take height of 10 % <div style="background:black;color:white;postion:fixed;height:10%">Rooms Names</div>

Comment: cool I'll submit an answer and add that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox makes a layout like this easy and very configurable. You can mix flex rows and columns to build each section, apply overflow, heights, and flex-grow where needed.

Here's a good reference on flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}

#chat-body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#chat-body, .message-center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.chat-header, footer {
  height: 10%;
}

.main, .message-center, .messages {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
}

.main > div:not(.message-center), .messages {
  overflow: auto;
}

.message-left, .message-right {
  width: 20%;
}

.names {
  height: 10%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat-body">
  <div class="chat-header">
    <span>chat Board</span>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="message-left">
      <ul>
        left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>v left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>left
        message
        <br><br><br>left message<br><br><br>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="message-center">
      <div class="names">Rooms Names</div>
      <ul class="messages">
        main message<br><br><br>main message<br><br><br>main message<br><br><br>main message<br><br><br>main message
        <br><br><br>main message
        <br><br><br>main message<br><br><br>main message
        <br><br><br>main message
        <br><br><br>main message
        <br><br><br>main message
        <br><br><br>main message
        <br><br><br>main message
        <br><br><br>main message
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="message-right">
      <ul>
        right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br> right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>
        <br><br>right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>right message<br><br><br>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
  <footer>
    My footer is here
  </footer>
</div>
```